# PHP showing last string value

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to display only last string value from string. This is my string `ShopTop205/12.50R15`

I want to just display this type of string

```
205/12.50R15
```

I have tried like

```
<?php 
$catName= 'ShopTop205/12.50R15';
echo substr($catName, strrpos($catName, ' ') + 1);
?>
```

second way

```
<?php
$string = 'ShopTop205/12.50R15';
$string = explode('', $string);
$last_string = end($string);
echo $last_string;
?>
```

I have used `substr()` function also but i could not get result that i want.

how could i do this ?

Comment: explode it with ShopTop and print the end element of array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may remove the initial non-numeric chars with a regex:

```
$catName= 'ShopTop205/12.50R15';
$res = preg_replace('~^\D+~', '', $catName);
echo $res; // => 205/12.50R15
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/S2Mmam)

The pattern is `^\D+` here, and it matches any one or more (`+`) chars other than digits (`\D`) at the start of the string (`^`).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xJw6Pb/1).

Comment: Yes. I like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$catName= 'ShopTop205/12.50R15';
$result = substr($catName, 7,20);
print $result;//205/12.50R15;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```
$catName= 'ShopTop205/12.50R15';
preg_match('/^\D*(?=\d)/', $catName, $m);
$pos = isset($m[0]) ? strlen($m[0]) : false;
$text = substr($catName,$pos); // this will contain 205/12.50R15
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it with substr() given that the length is always the same:

https://ideone.com/A4Avpt

```
<?php
echo substr('ShopTop205/12.50R15', -12);
?>
```

Output: `205/12.50R15`